# Theory about use of concept maps?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, performance, human-factors, visualization

My background is Computing Science and I want to research how people use concept maps? By doing some google search I found the following link
https://www.msu.edu/~luckie/ctools/

What I want to research is along the following lines of thought:

1. How do people use concept maps?
2. What benefits (cognitive or other) do concept maps offer?
3. How do concept maps help in making sense of data?

I am looking for existing research and theory around use of concept maps that is close to what I am thinking -- basically what research has already been done in the context of concept maps.

When I say "concept map", I am also open to other diagramming techniques like mind map, argument map etc.

Can you suggest some publications that I can read to understand what has been researched in the field on concept maps?

Comment: sorry for the tags. I am new to the field.